# Can't open image in gallery on API21 - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an application which displays images in the app from Firebase Storage. I have implemented that when you click on the image it should open up in the gallery so that the user has the ability zoom.

It runs fine on API 28 Emulator but when running it on API21 I get the following error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW *********
```

the code for this is:

```
photo2.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri2.toString()),"image/*")
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Is API21 not able to handle this type of intent action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API 21 can handle this type of intent action.

Maybe you don't have any app to open intent with `image/*` type on your device? Try `intent.resolveActivity()` to detect if you have any app able to handle intent.

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    //there is no activity for image/* intent
    //show popup?
    Log.w("PHOTO", "No activity to handle image/* intent");
}
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)

Comment: the Emulator does have Gallery installed on it.

Comment: When trying your suggestion, the app doesn't crash but it doesn't open the image in gallery either. nothing happens.

Comment: When `intent.resolveActivity` returns `null`, it means that there is no app/activity that can handle this type of intent on the device. Try installing another gallery app. You can also add `else` branch and show popup/toast for user, to let him know that there is some problem.